# Median of Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

How would you find the median of a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $n=5$ and $p=0.3?$

I thought that the median for a Bernoulli distribution was $0$ if $q>p;$ $.5$ if $q=p;$ and $1$ if $q< p.$ How do you apply this given specific parameters?

Comment: Do you mean Binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *Bernoulli* distribution, the main confusion occurs when $p = .5.$ Then
$P(X=0) = P(X = 1) = 1/2.$

According to one definition ***a***
median would be any number between $0$ and $1$ and many would
choose $1/2$ as the median. This definition is often used for data.
But for data, there are several definitions of quantiles, including
the median, are in common use.

Another definition, often used for
discrete distributions, is to
choose the smallest value $\eta$ for which $P(X \le \eta) \ge 1/2.$
Then $\eta = 0$ for $\mathsf{Bern}(p=1/2) \equiv \mathsf{Binom}(n=1,p=1/2).$

The latter definition is implemented in R statistical software (where Bernoulli is represented by binomial with $n=1)$ as
illustrated below:

```
p = seq(0,1, by=.1)
eta = qbinom(.5, 1, p)   # <- quantile .5, 50th percentile, median
cbind(p, eta)
       p eta
  ## 0.0   0
  ## 0.1   0
  ## 0.2   0
  ## 0.3   0    # <- median for BERN(.3)
  ## 0.4   0
  ## 0.5   0    # <- median for BERN(.5)
  ## 0.6   1
  ## 0.7   1
  ## 0.8   1
  ## 0.9   1
  ## 1.0   1
```

I think the most-commonly accepted answer for $\mathsf{Bern}(p=.3)$ would be $\eta = 0$ as shown above.

*There is no Bernoulli distribution* with $n = 5$ and $p = .3.$ You might have
the *binomial* distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p=.3)$ in mind. In that case
the median is $\eta = 1.$

```
qbinom(.5, 5, .3)
## 1
```

[Note: The *mean* of this binomial distribution is $np = 5(.3) = 1.5.$ As a general
rule, the *median* of a binomial distribution can be at $np,$ or at the next
smaller or larger integer to $np.$ See Wikipedia on 'binomial distribution'.]

The plot of the CDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(5, .3)$ below shows that its median is at $1.$ (Notice that $P(X = 5) = (.3)^5$ so that the 'jump' in the CDF at $x=5$ is
almost beyond the resolution o the graph.)

[image]